# Assigning new word by creating a new column when finding match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a survey df and I want to assign a new value of either existing customer 
    or new customer based on their answers. if someone has 3 answers but one of 
    them matches "coca cola" I want to give them the value of existing customer 
     here is the data frame

```
ID       Question                                                Answer
101005   what brands did you purchase the past 5 months   Coca-Cola or Pepsi or vitamin water
026458   what brands did you purchase the past 5 months           None
045987   what brands  did you purchase the past 5 months        Coca-Cola
```

Here is the table I would like to have

```
ID        Question                                          Answer                      Buyer_Type
101005   what brands did you purchase the past 5 months  Coca-Cola,Pepsi,fanta          Existing Users          
026458   what brands did you purchase the past 5 months  None                           New Buyer              
045987   what brands did you purchase the past 5 months  Coca-Cola                      Existing Users
```

Here is what I tried

```
deux['Buyer_Type'] = deux['answer'].apply(lambda x: 'existing buyer' if x == 'Coca-Cola' else 'new buyer')
```

For some reasons it is not recognizing 101005 as an existing user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the results you're expecting because you're explicitly comparing the value in the `Answer` column to 'Coca-Cola' (i.e `x == 'Coca-Cola'`) but the value in that column is (I'm assuming) a `list` or a `string`. In either case comparing it to 'Coca-Cola' would result in `False`.
What you need to do is change your condition to check in 'Coca-Cola' appears anywhere in the `list` or `string`.
Here's one way of achieving this (I'm assuming the `Answer` column contains lists):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
          "ID": ["101005", "026458", "045987"], 
          "Question": ["what brands did you purchase the past 5 months", 
                       "what brands did you purchase the past 5 months",
                       "what brands did you purchase the past 5 months "],
          "Answer": [["Coca-Cola" ,"Pepsi" ,"fanta"], [None], ["Coca-Cola"]]
}
deux = pd.DataFrame(data)
deux['Buyer_Type'] = deux['Answer'].apply(lambda x: 'existing buyer' if 'Coca-Cola' in x else 'new buyer')
```